# custom adapter showing wrong items

Tags: java, android, custom-adapter

I have a problem with my adapter when calling .notifyDataSetChanged(). It's showing wrong items

**Problem:**

I have 3 items saved in my `ArrayList`: Item 1, Item 2 and Item 3. When i remove for example Item 1 using `.remove(Index)` item 1 gets removed, but after calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` my `ListView` is showing: Item 1 and Item 2, last one is not showing, even when my `ArrayList` contains only Item 2 and Item 3.

Code and output below:

```
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {


                final int indexToDelete = i;
                Log.i("indexToDelete", Integer.toString(i));
                for (int ji = 0; ji < items.size(); ji ++ ) {

                    Log.i("ItemInside",items.get(ji).getItemName());

                }

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(UserSimplePlusNoteActivity.this);
                builder.setTitle("Do you want to delete this note?");
                builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                        final Item toDelete = items.get(indexToDelete);
                        String noteToDelete = toDelete.getItemName();

                        items.remove(indexToDelete);
                        for (int ji = 0; ji < items.size(); ji ++ ) {

                            Log.i("ItemInside2",items.get(ji).getItemName());

                        }
                        customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Log output before delete:

```
03-29 14:00:19.118 23457-23457/com.example.user.testingapp I/indexToDelete: 0
03-29 13:47:08.202 22165-22165/com.example.user.testingapp I/ItemInside: Test 1
03-29 13:47:08.202 22165-22165/com.example.user.testingapp I/ItemInside: Test 2 
03-29 13:47:08.202 22165-22165/com.example.user.testingapp I/ItemInside: Test 3
```

After delete:

```
03-29 13:47:08.202 22165-22165/com.example.user.testingapp I/ItemInside: Test 2 
03-29 13:47:08.202 22165-22165/com.example.user.testingapp I/ItemInside: Test 3
```

[App screen is showing this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ajawn.png)

And here's my Adapter and Item:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Item> items;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> items) {

        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return items.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(view == null) {

            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_adapter, parent, false);

            Item currentItem = (Item) getItem(position);

            TextView textViewItemName = view.findViewById(R.id.titleID);
            TextView textViewItemDescription = view.findViewById(R.id.detailID);
            ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imgID);

            textViewItemName.setText(currentItem.getItemName());
            textViewItemDescription.setText(currentItem.getItemDescription());
            switch (currentItem.getPriority()) {

                case 1:
                    break;
                case 2:
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.priority_urgent_icon);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.priority_important_icon);
                    break;
                    default:
                        Log.i("Ok", "Something strange happend");


            }

        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

Item:

```
public class Item {
    private String itemName;
    private String itemDescription;
    private int priority;

    public Item(String name, String description, int priority) {
        this.itemName = name;
        this.itemDescription = description;
        this.priority = priority;

    }

    public String getItemName() {

        return this.itemName;
    }

    public String getItemDescription() {

        return this.itemDescription;

    }

    public int getPriority() {

        return this.priority;

    }

}
```

Comment: print the `items` in your `customAdapter` and post the result here

Comment: You're not handling things correctly in your `Adapter`'s `getView()` method. Even when `view` is not null, you still need to set the texts and image on your `View`s there. With your current approach, the only thing you should be doing in `if(view == null)` is inflating the item layout. You can simply move the `}` right above the `return` statement to right after the `view = ...` line.

Comment: @MikeM. You're right, that fixed it, thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

It seems `notifyDataSetChanged()` doesn't properly refresh in this case. Refreshing the `customAdapter` with new `items` and setting this to listView i.e these two lines before `notifyDataSetChanged()` however solves the issue:

```
customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), items);
listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```